# Debugging nested for loops in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, nested

This is for a Python project. My while loops does not appear to stop once the condition is met and my program returns an error where it claims the 'list index is out of range', any insight on my error? It seems to lie within the variable 'v' not incrementing as wanted.

code:

```
import csv
file = open("stocklist.csv","r")

stocklist = csv.reader(file)

slist = []
quant = []
x = "yes"
amofitems = 0

while x != 'no':
    GTIN = input("What is the GTIN-8 number of your desired item? ")
    slist.append(GTIN)
    #quan = input("How many of this item do you require? ")
    #quant.append(quan)
    amofitems = amofitems + 1
    x = input("Do you wish to purchase another item? Yes/No ").lower()

product = []
v = 0

while v < amofitems:
    for row in stocklist:
        print(row)
        for item in row:
            print(item)
            if item == slist[v]:
                print("Object found")
                product.append(row[1])
                quant.append(row[2])
            print("row:",v)

        v = v + 1
        print("V:",v)

print ("Your selected item is", product, "with a price of")   
file.close()
```

Comment: Please include the actual error you are seeing, including stack trace.

Comment: @alfasin I suppose it's because of this part of the question: "program returns an error where it claims the 'list index is out of range'"

Comment: Are you sure you want to `v = v + 1` to be executed where you put it ? what if the first for-loop is never executed because `stocklist` is empty ?

Comment: @TemporalWolf you're right! comment removed.

Comment: stocklist definitely has values inside

Comment: @AdamK I suspect that within 5 minutes of you posting a stack trace you'll have a solution... they are really helpful for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `v` should not be incremented inside the `for` loop, and that section of code should instead be:

```
while v < amofitems:
    for row in stocklist:
        print(row)
        for item in row:
            print(item)
            if item == slist[v]:
                print("Object found")
                product.append(row[1])
                quant.append(row[2])
            print("row:",v)

    v = v + 1        # different indentation here
    print("V:",v)
```

Note that there are a few ways your code could be tidied up in general. For example, you could avoid needing to maintain indices entirely by using `enumerate`:

```
for i, v in enumerate(slist):
    for row in stocklist:
        print(row)
        for item in row:
            print(item)
            if item == slist[i]:
                print("Object found")
                product.append(row[1])
                quant.append(row[2])
```